# How to bind the <M-s> key in Emacs

Tags: emacs

Using Emacs 24.3.1 if I press <kbd>M-s</kbd> I get I-search. I would like this functionality to move to key <kbd>C-f</kbd>, and use <kbd>M-s</kbd> to save the buffer. How can I do that?

Comment: Be aware that there are useful bindings on the `M-s` prefix that you will lose by doing that (type `M-s C-h` to see them). Other libraries may also *expect* it to be a global prefix that they can add things to, in which case you might encounter errors at that time.

Comment: Of course isearch is actually on `C-s`, not `M-s`, so your question is confusing.

Comment: Perhaps you want to look at [`cua-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CuaMode) if you want "traditional desktop" keybindings.  You will be losing out on important Emacs functionality, though.  Better to learn *The Way* and forget your sordid past.

Comment: You ask to very danger changes that may break your Emacs usage experience. Try to look for build-in tutorial or fast leaning guides in Internet. Also look to `Ergo Emacs` attempt to make key binding easy for some users http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_keys_index.html

Comment: Ok, I have been convinced to leave things as they are as much as possible. But still I have search on both `C-s` and `M-s` which is kind of a waste so I would like to bind `M-s` to save-buffer, but it seems like it can't be done. And this is confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```el
(global-set-key "\C-f" 'isearch-forward)
(define-key isearch-mode-map "\C-f" 'isearch-repeat-forward)
(global-set-key "\M-s" 'save-buffer)
```

into your `~/.emacs/init.el` (or `~/.emacs`, or `~/.emacs.el`). Then restart emacs (or put the cursor after each line and press C-x C-e).

**Addendum:** Since something seems to bind the key combinations after OP's `~/.emacs` is loaded: A way to delay running this code, hopefully until late enough, is to use `after-init-hook`. For example:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook
   (lambda()
      (global-set-key "\C-f" 'isearch-forward)
      (define-key isearch-mode-map "\C-f" 'isearch-repeat-forward)
      (global-set-key "\M-s" 'save-buffer)))
```

Mind you, I am not entirely convinced that it is a good idea to battle an installed library for key bindings. It's probably a good idea to find out what rebinds these key combinations and see if it can be persuaded to stop.

Comment: I have added the three lines above to my ~/.emacs file, and these are the only three lines that I have in that file, and I still get search when I press <M-s>. <C-h k> says

Comment: As @phils says, isearch is usually `C-s`. If you mean to remap that, use `"\C-s"` instead of `"\M-s"` in the above code. Otherwise, there's something else happening at startup to bind `M-s` to isearch. Wild guess: If you have a `~/.emacs.el`, `~/.emacs` will not be executed. Perhaps it's happening there.

Comment: Forgive me, my previous comment wasn't complete.  Here is what confuses me. What I have is an empty ~/.emacs.d folder and an ~/.emacs file with the three lines above. If I press <M-s> I get the search. So I was curious what does <C-h k> report on <M-s>, and it says the very same thing as for <C-s> which confuses me because I thought that I have bound save-buffer to <M-s>. Could it be that some other library "binds back" the search to <M-s> after .emacs is read?

Comment: It's possible. After your `~/.emacs`, the site's `default.el` is loaded (you can prevent that by setting `inhibit-default-init` to a non-`nil` value), and there's also `after-init-hook` (see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Init-File.html). I suppose you could use `after-init-hook` to run the code in the answer after all that happens.

Comment: Torok Balint: If you start Emacs by running `emacs -Q`, do you still find `M-s` bound to isearch?

Comment: I had to reinstall the whole box, and so Emacs as well, and now the bindings above work perfectly. I'm really not sure where was the problem. Anyway thank you everyone for the help.